# Casting (double *) to (double **) allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

Because I followed a discussion where was told "Aliasing through incompatible pointer types is undefined behavior" (e.g. `double d; int *p = (int *)&d;` following question:

Is it allowed to cast an `(double *)` to `(double **)`, e.g. `double *d1; double **d2 = &d2` **and** using syntax like `d2[0][y]` expecting to be the same as `d1[y]`?

I know that it is not exactly aliasing through incompatible pointer types, but however I am not sure. Background is that I want to have a function which operates on 2-dimensional arrays (= images) but I want to be able to pass only a row or column of an image.

Comment: You don't do casting. In fact, **double **d2 = &d1** is valid.

Comment: In the first para, do you mean `double d; int *p = (int *)&d;` ..?

Comment: @user1158692: yes, i corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double**` is incompatible with `double*`.  The conversion is legal, but the only thing you can do with the results is cast it back.  This seems more or less obvious: on a 32 bit machine, a `double*` won't even have the same size as a `double`.

But your example *doesn't* convert a `double*` to `double**`.  It creates a new `double**`, which points to the `double*`.  This is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it allowed to cast an (double *) to (double **), e.g. double *d1; double **d2 = &d2 and using syntax like d2[0][y] expecting to be the same as d1[y]?

Of course not, and it [won't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39b6887dfb21bb82).

But if you meant:

```
double *d1; 
double **d2 = &d2;
```

then yes, the above is perfectly valid and since `d2[0][y]` can be seen as `(*d2)[y]`, there's really no problem at all.

Finally, remember that in the above code, you are not casting anything: `&d2` is already of type `double**`. If you have to cast something, please use C++ style casts (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, etc..) and not C style casts.